# How start intellij idea terminal with different folder?

Tags: command-line, intellij-idea, terminal

Command line terminal stars with some folder like `projectRoot/one subproject` every time instead of `projectRoot`. Personally I did not change any settings for that.

Does any body know how setup Idea to start terminal with project root instead of typing `cd ..` every time?

Comment: as far as I know IntelliJ hasn't this function yet, it's not a professional terminal tool after all.

Comment: And are there plans to make it as professional?

Comment: Feel free to file a request at JetBrain's issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

There's already a request:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125383

Answer (score 6):

I don't quite understand how the Terminal Plugin in IDEA figures out where to start the terminal (though it is always a subfolder of the project root), but there is a sort of workaround for this: always start the terminal in the root of your repo.

In "Settings -> Terminal", add the /K option followed by a command to navigate to the desired path, e.g.:

- Shell path: `cmd /K "cd D:\usr\local\repo"`

Comment: Voted up, but much good solution is ro set it once for all projects :)